# Fastest way to count words in a google research?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to count occurrence of a word in a google research and that quickly.
Actually, this portion of my program take 1.2 second to run and it's too much I think.

---

### My current program is :

```
#qt is my keyword 
values = {'q': qt}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
url = "http://www.google.fr/search?" + data
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
response = urlopen(req).read().lower()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
resp = soup.get_text()

count = sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(unidecode.unidecode(word)), str(resp)))
```

---

unidecode is to remove accented characters to avoid errors. I think there is faster but I have not found

Thanks,

Comment: what have you timed exactly (the whole script or just the last line) and how did you time it?

Comment: Keep a local copy of the search result `soup.get_text()` and try out your code on that.

Comment: I use the module time to this and I time all the program

Comment: could you just run grep instead?

Comment: What is grep please ?

Comment: What is `word`?

Comment: word is the word I want to count the number of occurrences

Answer (score 1):

a simple split can give the answer you're searching, fast. using `SoupStrainer` and letting python3 do the unicode stuff itself might improve also but not by much

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml", parse_only=SoupStrainer(id="rso"))
resp = soup.get_text()
count2 = len(resp.split(word))-1
```

Comment: I try do to this but the program takes the same time to execute, there are no others methods to access to the content of a google search and count occurrences more quickly ?

Comment: i misunderstood the question, sorry

Comment: Can there be other ways to count the number of occurrences of a word in a google search more quickly?